# Problems in changing projection using georeferencer in QGIS

Tags: qgis, georeferencing

I'm an amateur user and primarily use QGIS to change the projections of my fantasy maps, using the Georeferencer functon. Normally I enter non-equirectangular projections, plot the co-ordinates and export the image in an equirectangular projection. this is the extent of my experience using QGIS.

Anyway. I'm trying to do the opposite - I'm drawing an equirectangular map and have imported it into the QGIS Georeferencer, entered the co-ordinates and am trying to export in a non-equirectangular (Lambert equal area, if it matters), but it just keeps on exporting it as equirectangular. I'm not sure If I'm doing anything wrong. I've tried exporting in various different projections and after rendering, the exported image is always identical to the original one.

How can I make this work?

[image]

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works.

Comment: When sharing some more details about the steps you've taken, include a screenshot of the georeferencer settings you've used (particularly the transformation type and destination CRS).

Answer (score 1):

Since this hasn't been answered I'll try to help. In Transformation Settings window set Target SRS to what the map **is originally** drawn in (equirectangular).
Add it as a new raster layer (via the main QGIS window Layer menu or ctrl+shift+R) to a project. Change the project CRS from the default EPSG:4326 to ESRI:102017 (an icon in the very bottom right of the screen). Create a new print layout via Project menu or ctrl+p. There (this should be covered by many tutorials so I won't go into detail) you can add your map and export it as an image.